# Enviar dois campos do txt via soap usando PHP

Tags: php, soap

Preciso pegar os valores de dois campos de um arquivo em `.txt` e enviar via *Soap*.

O envio *Soap* já está funcionando, quando insiro o *Barcode* e `absoluteQuantity` ele envia o valor certinho, porem agora preciso fazer com que esse campo seja alimentado pelo arquivo do `.txt`, veja imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<?php    
    $client = new SoapClient('http://rcs01-sales.fftech.info/pub/apistock.asmx?wsdl');
    $function = 'BarcodeProcessAbsoluteQuantity';
    $arguments= array('BarcodeProcessAbsoluteQuantity' => array(
                        'Key'   => '5VWyXKYZxH0=',
                        'Barcode'                 => 8054182140865,
                        'absoluteQuantity'        => 2,
                        'ErrMsg'      => '0',
                        'IsAdjustment'      => '0',
                        'currentStock'      => '0',
                ));

    $options = array('location' => 'http://rcs01-sales.fftech.info/pub/apistock.asmx?wsdl');
    $result = $client->__soapCall($function, $arguments, $options);

    echo 'RESPOSTA:';
    print_r($result);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Basta você ler o conteúdo do arquivo utilizando `file_get_contents` e percorrer as linhas pela quebra de `\n` e também `;`.

```
$txtContent = "1;1\n2;2\n3;3"; // file_get_contents('file.txt');

$arrayContent = explode("\n", $txtContent);

foreach ($arrayContent as $string) {
    list($barcode, $absoluteQuantity) = explode(';', $string);

    echo "Bardcode {$barcode} with {$absoluteQuantity} quantity\n";
}
```

Live: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b88e59fbfd59f291bb343a218587434f2d84c436

Comment: Obrigado Junior!

Infelizmente usando dessa forma tenho um problema com o envio para o webservice (SOAP).

Comment: Ahn? Que problema?

Comment: Ele apenas enviar a primeira linha do barcode.

Comment: Então o envio esta fora do loop, envie seu código.

Comment: O código ficou assim:

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/237698/91056

Comment: E esta errado. A chama de SOAP deve ficar dentro do `foreach`.

Comment: Amigo, muito obrigado !! DEU CERTO.